# Empty dictionary error when attempting delete on sqldatasource

Tags: vb.net, datasource, sql-delete

I'm trying to make a simple Gridview using vb.net and asp (visual studio 2008) website that works with a single table in an sql database. I have manually written all statements, they are not automatically generated (Delete, Insert, Update).  Insert and Update work fine and commit to the database. When trying to delete, I get this error:

"You have specified that your delete command compares all values on SqlDataSource 'mydatasource', but the dictionary passed in for values is empty. Pass in a valid dictionary for delete or change your mode to OverwriteChanges."

I've been reading about optimistic concurrency being enabled corrects this, but I don't know how to enable it other than when letting the datasource autogenerate the update, delete, insert statements.  I'm not doing that here.  This very same code works in another project I'm working on so I am at a loss.  Any help is very much appreciated.

```
******************************************ASP CODE***************************************************

<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" tagprefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-
transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title> OnCall Schedule </title>
<style type="text/css">
    #form1
    {
        height: 731px;
        width: 1122px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmDefault" method="post" runat="server">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
                    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager> 
<div>

</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsOncallGroup" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DiscussSQLConnectionString %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tblOnCall WHERE (tblOnCall.fldOnCallGroup = @fldOnCallGroup) 
                   AND (tblOnCall.fldEndOnCall &gt; GETDATE()) 
                   ORDER BY tblOnCall.fldOnCallGroup, tblOnCall.fldEndOnCall, tblOnCall.fldRank" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM tblOnCall WHERE fldOCID = @fldOCID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblOnCall] ([fldOnCallGroup], [fldStartOnCall], [fldEndOnCall], [fldRank], 
[fldEmpName], [fldEmpWorkPhone],
                   [fldEmpHomePhone],[fldEmpHomeCellPhone],[fldEmpAltPhone],[fldOCPreferredContact]) 
 VALUES (@fldOnCallGroup, @fldStartOnCall, @fldEndOnCall, @fldRank, @fldEmpName, @fldEmpWorkPhone, @fldEmpHomePhone, 
                           @fldEmpHomeCellPhone, @fldEmpAltPhone, @fldOCPreferredContact)" 



    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblOnCall] SET [fldOnCallGroup] = @fldOnCallGroup, [fldStartOnCall] = @fldStartOnCall, 
[fldEndOnCall] = @fldEndOnCall, [fldRank] = @fldRank, [fldEmpName] = @fldEmpName, [fldEmpWorkPhone] = 
@fldEmpWorkPhone,
[fldEmpHomePhone] = @fldEmpHomePhone,[fldEmpHomeCellPhone] = @fldEmpHomeCellPhone,[fldEmpAltPhone] = @fldEmpAltPhone,
                   [fldOCPreferredContact] = @fldOCPreferredContact
                   WHERE [fldOCID] = @original_fldOCID">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboOncallGroup" Name="fldOnCallGroup" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldOCID" Type="Int16" />          
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldStartOnCall" DbType ="DateTime2" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEndOnCall" DbType ="DateTime2" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldStartOnCall" DbType="DateTime2" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEndOnCall" DbType="DateTime2" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="fldStartOnCall" />
        <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime2" Name="fldEndOnCall" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldOnCallGroup" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldStartOnCall" DbType="DateTime2" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_fldEndOnCall" DbType="DateTime2" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldRank" Type="Int16" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpWorkPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpHomePhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpHomeCellPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldEmpAltPhone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name= "original_fldOCPreferredContact" Type="String" />
      </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsListbox" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DiscussSQLConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [fldOnCallGroup] FROM [tblOnCall]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>




<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div style="margin-left: 50px">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100px" 
    ImageUrl="~/images/ITSLogo.jpg" Width="100px" />
   <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> 


<asp:DropDownList ID="cboOncallGroup" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsListbox" DataTextField="fldOnCallGroup" 
    DataValueField="fldOnCallGroup" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboOnCallGroup_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Height="19px" Width="237px">
</asp:DropDownList>
</div> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsEmp" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DiscussSQLConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [fldEmpName] FROM [tblOnCall]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br /> <br /> 
<div style="margin-left: 50px">
    <asp:Gridview ID="gvOnCallSchedule" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" showfooter="true"
        OnRowUpdating="GvOnCall_Update" onRowCommand="gvOnCallSchedule_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="fldOCID"
        BackColor="Aqua" DataSourceID="dsOncallGroup" Font-Bold="True" 
        Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" 
        Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Justify" 
        CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboOnCallGroup_SelectedIndexChanged">

        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false"> 
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="AddButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" ImageURL="~/images/New.png" 
                         Text="Add" ToolTip="Add New On Call Record" />                
                </FooterTemplate>

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Update" 
                                ImageUrl="~/images/Save.png" Text="Update" ToolTip="Update" />
                                &nbsp;
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Cancel"
                                ImageURL="~/images/Cancel.png" Text="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" />
                </EditItemTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" 
                                ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.gif" Text="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" />
                                &nbsp;
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
                                ImageUrl="~/images/Delete.png" Text="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />   
            </asp:TemplateField>       

            <asp:Boundfield headertext="fldOCID" datafield="fldOCID" sortexpression="fldOCID" visible="false" 
InsertVisible="False" />               

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="On Call Group">
                <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOCGroup" width="250px" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldOnCallGroup" Enabled="false"
                        DataSourceID= "dsListbox" SelectedValue="<%# Bind('fldOnCallGroup') %>"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ftrddlOCGroup" width="250px" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldOnCallGroup"
                        DataSourceID= "dsListbox" SelectedValue="<%# Bind('fldOnCallGroup') %>"> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Start Date/Time">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtStartOnCall" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldStartOnCall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="StartOnCallCal" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartOnCall" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopup" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtStartOnCallFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldStartOncall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopupFtr" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />    
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="StartOnCallCalFtr" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtStartOnCallFtr" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopupFtr" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>

                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="End Date/Time">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtEndOnCall" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEndOnCall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopup2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="EndOnCallCal" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndOnCall" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopup2" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtEndOnCallFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEndOnCall") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                    <asp:Image ID="calpopup2Ftr" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/calendar2.png" />    
                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="EndOnCallCalFtr" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndOnCallFtr" 
                            PopupButtonID="calpopup2Ftr" PopupPosition="Right" format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>

                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Call Order">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblCallOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldRank") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtCallOrderFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldOnCallGroup") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OnCall Analyst">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnalyst" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldEmpName"
                    datasourceID="dsEmp" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("fldEmpName") %>'> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnalystFtr" runat="server" datavaluefield="fldEmpName"
                        DataSourceID= "dsEmp" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("fldEmpName") %>'> 
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField headertext="Work Phone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblWorkPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpWorkPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtWorkPhoneFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpWorkPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Home Phone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblHomePhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomePhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtHomePhoneFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomePhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Personal Cell">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblHomeCellPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomeCellPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtHomeCellPhoneFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpHomeCellPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Alternate Phone">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Textbox ID="lblAltPhone" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpAltPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
                    <asp:Textbox ID="txtAltPhoneFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldEmpAltPhone") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField headertext="Preferred Contact">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Textbox ID="lblOCPreferredContact" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldOCPreferredContact") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>              
              <asp:Textbox ID="txtOCPreferredContactFtr" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fldOCPreferredContact") %>'> 
                        </asp:Textbox>
                </FooterTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    </asp:Gridview>
</div>
  <br />
<br />
<div style="margin-left: 200px">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>


***************************************VB.net Code behind****************************************

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.DataRowView

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub cboOnCallGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles   
cboOncallGroup.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Dim cboAssignedFK As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim cboOnCallGroup As String = TryCast(sender, DropDownList).SelectedValue
    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
("DiscussSQLConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim sSql As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = <sql>

        SELECT [fldOnCallGroup], [fldStartOnCall], [fldEndOnCall], [fldRank], [fldEmpName], [fldEmpWorkPhone],
               [fldEmpHomePhone], [fldEmpHomeCellPhone], [fldEmpAltPhone], [fldOCPreferredContact] 
        FROM [tblOnCall]

        WHERE ([fldOnCallGroup] = '<%= cboOnCallGroup %>') 
        ORDER BY [fldOnCallGroup], [fldEndOnCall], [fldRank] </sql>


    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sSql.Value, sqlConn)
    Dim sqlRead As SqlDataReader
    If sqlConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        sqlConn.Open()
    End If
    sqlRead = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
    sqlRead.Read()

    sqlRead.Close()
    sqlConn.Close()

End Sub

Function SendSQLCommand(ByVal tsSQLCmd As String, ByVal tsqlConn As SqlConnection) As Integer
    Dim iRetVal As Integer = -1
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(tsSQLCmd, tsqlConn)
    If tsqlConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        tsqlConn.Open()
    End If
    Try
        iRetVal = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return iRetVal
End Function

Function SendSQLCommand2(ByVal tsSQLCmd As String, ByVal tsqlConn As SqlConnection) As Integer
    Dim iRetVal As Integer = -1
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(tsSQLCmd, tsqlConn)
    If tsqlConn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        tsqlConn.Open()
    End If

    Return iRetVal
End Function
Protected Sub GvOnCall_Update(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim keyValue As Integer = e.Keys("fldOCID")
    Dim strfldOnCallGroupOld As String = RTrim(LTrim(e.OldValues("fldOnCallGroup").ToString()))
    Dim strfldOnCallGroupNew As String = RTrim(LTrim(e.NewValues("fldOnCallGroup").ToString()))
    Dim strfldStartOnCallOld As String = RTrim(LTrim(e.OldValues("fldStartOnCall").ToString()))
    Dim strfldStartOnCallNew As String = RTrim(LTrim(e.NewValues("fldStartOnCall").ToString()))
    Dim strfldEndOnCallOld As String = RTrim(LTrim(e.OldValues("fldEndOnCall").ToString()))
    Dim strfldEndOnCallNew As String = RTrim(LTrim(e.NewValues("fldEndOnCall").ToString()))
    Dim strfldRankOld As Int32 = e.OldValues("fldRank")
    Dim strfldRankNew As Int32 = e.NewValues("fldRank")
    Dim strfldEmpNameOld As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpName")
    Dim strfldEmpNameNew As String = e.NewValues("fldEmpName")
    Dim strfldEmpWorkPhoneOld As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpWorkPhone")
    Dim strfldEmpWorkPhoneNew As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpWorkPhone")
    Dim strfldEmpHomePhoneOld As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpHomePhone")
    Dim strfldEmpHomePhoneNew As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpHomePhone")
    Dim strfldEmpHomeCellPhoneOld As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpHomeCellPhone")
    Dim strfldEmpHomeCellPhoneNew As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpHomeCellPhone")
    Dim strfldEmpAltPhoneOld As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpAltPhone")
    Dim strfldEmpAltPhoneNew As String = e.OldValues("fldEmpAltPhone")
    Dim strfldOnCallCellPhoneOld As String = e.OldValues("fldOnCallCellPhone")
    Dim strfldOnCallCellPhoneNew As String = e.OldValues("fldOnCallCellPhone")
    Dim fldOCPreferredContactOld As String = e.OldValues("fldOCPreferredContact")
    Dim fldOCPreferredContactNew As String = e.OldValues("fldOCPreferredContact")


    gvOnCall_Updated(keyValue, strfldOnCallGroupNew, strfldStartOnCallNew, strfldEndOnCallNew, strfldRankNew, 
strfldEmpNameNew, _
strfldEmpWorkPhoneNew, strfldEmpHomePhoneNew, strfldEmpHomeCellPhoneNew, strfldEmpAltPhoneNew, 
strfldOnCallCellPhoneNew, fldOCPreferredContactNew)

End Sub

Protected Sub gvOnCall_Updated(ByVal fldOCID As Integer, ByVal fldOnCallGroup As String, ByVal fldStartOnCall As 
String, ByVal fldEndOnCall As String, _
                              ByVal fldRank As Integer, ByVal fldEmpName As String, ByVal fldEmpWorkPhone As String, 
ByVal fldEmpHomePhone As String, _
          ByVal fldEmpHomeCellPhone As String, ByVal fldEmpAltPhone As String, ByVal fldOnCallCellPhone As String, 
ByVal fldOCPreferredContact As String)
Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
("DiscussSQLConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim sSql As XElement
    sSql = <sql>
        Update [tblOncall] SET [fldOnCallGroup] = '<%= fldOnCallGroup %>', 
               [fldStartOnCall] = '<%= [fldStartOnCall] %>',[fldEndOnCall] = '<%= [fldEndOnCall] %>', 
[fldRank] = '<%= [fldRank] %>', [fldEmpName] = '<%= [fldEmpName] %>', [fldEmpWorkPhone] = '<%= [fldEmpWorkPhone] %>',
              [fldEmpHomePhone] = '<%= [fldEmpHomePhone] %>', [fldEmpHomeCellPhone] = '<%= [fldEmpHomeCellPhone] %>',
             [fldEmpAltPhone] = '<%= [fldEmpAltPhone] %>', [fldOCPreferredContact] = '<%= [fldOCPreferredContact] %>'
        Where  [fldOCID] = '<%= [fldOCID] %>' </sql>

    'MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")

    SendSQLCommand(sSql.Value, sqlConn)
    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub

Protected Sub gvOnCallSchedule_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   

System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs) Handles gvOnCallSchedule.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "Insert" AndAlso Page.IsValid Then
        Try
            dsOncallGroup.Insert()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
            'MsgBox("An error occured.  Please ensure all required fields are entered and that the Application you 
 are trying to add doesn't already exist.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Database Error")
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
        End Try

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    End If


    If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
        Try
            dsOncallGroup.Delete()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
            'MsgBox("Application Deleted Successfully")
        End Try

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")

    End If


    End Sub


    Protected Sub dsOnCallGroup_Inserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs) Handles 
    dsOncallGroup.Inserting
    Dim strddlGroupName As New DropDownList
    Dim txtStartOnCall As New TextBox
    Dim txtEndOnCall As New TextBox
    Dim txtRank As New TextBox
    Dim strddlEmpName As New DropDownList
    Dim txtEmpWorkPhone As New TextBox
    Dim txtEmpHomePhone As New TextBox
    Dim txtEmpHomeCellPhone As New TextBox
    Dim txtEmpAltPhone As New TextBox
    Dim txtOCPreferredContact As New TextBox


    strddlGroupName = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("ftrddlOCGroup"), DropDownList)
    txtStartOnCall = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStartOnCallFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEndOnCall = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndOnCallFtr"), TextBox)
    txtRank = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCallOrderFtr"), TextBox)
    strddlEmpName = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlAnalystFtr"), DropDownList)
    txtEmpWorkPhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtWorkPhoneFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEmpHomePhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHomePhoneFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEmpHomeCellPhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtHomeCellPhoneFtr"), TextBox)
    txtEmpAltPhone = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAltPhoneFtr"), TextBox)
    txtOCPreferredContact = CType(gvOnCallSchedule.FooterRow.FindControl("txtOCPreferredContactFtr"), TextBox)

    e.Command.Parameters("@fldOnCallGroup").Value = strddlGroupName.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldStartOnCall").Value = txtStartOnCall.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEndOnCall").Value = txtEndOnCall.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldRank").Value = txtRank.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpName").Value = strddlEmpName.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpWorkPhone").Value = txtEmpWorkPhone.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpHomePhone").Value = txtEmpHomePhone.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpHomeCellPhone").Value = txtEmpHomeCellPhone.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldEmpAltPhone").Value = txtEmpAltPhone.Text
    e.Command.Parameters("@fldOCPreferredContact").Value = txtOCPreferredContact.Text
    'MsgBox(strddlGroup.Text, MsgBoxStyle.Information)


    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set

```
ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges"
```

In your

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsOncallGroup" runat="server"
```

see: [SqlDataSource.ConflictDetection Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.conflictdetection.aspx)

Comment: I tried that.  It gets rid of the error, however, the delete doesnt commit to the database.  If I remove the conflictdetection line of code altogether, the delete commits to the database.  Is there a downside of leaving that line out?

Comment: `ConflictOptions` Enumeration has two values `OverwriteChanges` and `CompareAllValues`. `CompareAllValues` tries to compare all values and there is by my opinion you exception.  `OverwriteChanges` is said to be default (see the link) and the situation should be the same as if you remove the conflictdetection line. But there should be origina exception again, is not it?